# app crashes when i start Activity while incoming call in android

Tags: android, eclipse, crash

I want to start Another Activity while incoming call in Android. Following is the code I found on a website. The code works perfect to pop up window while incoming call but when I try to start Activity by passing intent(missintent) the app crashes.
Note: App only crashes while incoming call. The method that i call my missintent is working fine when i call at any other time other than incoming call.

```
package com.bitgriff.androidcalls;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Helper class to detect incoming and outgoing calls.
 * @author Moskvichev Andrey V.
 *
 */
public class CallHelper extends Activity{

    /**
     * Listener to detect incoming calls. 
     */
    private class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                // called when someone is ringing to this phone

                Toast.makeText(ctx, 
                        "Incoming: "+incomingNumber, 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //app crashes due to following 3 lines. Above toast works perfectly
                Intent missintent= new Intent(ctx, LEDOnOff.class); 
                missintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(missintent);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Broadcast receiver to detect the outgoing calls.
     */
    public class OutgoingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public OutgoingReceiver() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

            Toast.makeText(ctx, 
                    "Outgoing: "+number, 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    private Context ctx;
    private TelephonyManager tm;
    private CallStateListener callStateListener;

    private OutgoingReceiver outgoingReceiver;

    public CallHelper(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;

        callStateListener = new CallStateListener();
        outgoingReceiver = new OutgoingReceiver();
    }

    /**
     * Start calls detection.
     */
    public void start() {
        tm = (TelephonyManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL);
        ctx.registerReceiver(outgoingReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    /**
     * Stop calls detection.
     */
    public void stop() {
        tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        ctx.unregisterReceiver(outgoingReceiver);
    }

}
```

following logcat errors are shown:

```
02-14 14:10:10.155: D/AndroidRuntime(29294): Shutting down VM
02-14 14:10:10.155: W/dalvikvm(29294): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4181eda0)
02-14 14:10:10.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29294): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-14 14:10:10.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29294): Process: com.bitgriff.androidcalls, PID: 29294
02-14 14:10:10.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29294): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-14 14:10:10.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29294):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3584)
02-14 14:10:10.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29294):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3545)
02-14 14:10:10.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29294):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3787)
02-14 14:10:10.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29294):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3755)
02-14 14:10:10.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29294):    at com.bitgriff.androidcalls.CallHelper$CallStateListener.onCallStateChanged(CallHelper.java:35)
02-14 14:10:10.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29294):    at android.telephony.PhoneStateListener$2.handleMessage(PhoneStateListener.java:461)
02-14 14:10:10.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29294):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-14 14:10:10.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29294):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
02-14 14:10:10.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29294):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
02-14 14:10:10.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29294):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-14 14:10:10.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29294):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-14 14:10:10.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29294):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
02-14 14:10:10.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29294):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
02-14 14:10:10.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29294):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Its hard to say whats wrong without logs. Use your phone as emulator and try it will give you logs.

Comment: I have added the logcat outputs.

Comment: `NullPointerException` tells you that you try to dereference a pointer that is null. The stack trace further tells you that it happens in `CallHelper.java` in line 35. Check this line to find out which variable may be null.

Comment: @Henry.. whatever you told, I already know. The app crashes because of intent to start the new activity but what is the solution to it?? Until my knowledge this is the correct way to define intent and start another activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you instantiate the class `CallHelper` manually. Since it inherits from `Activity` you should never do that. Activities are always started by the framework.

There are two possibilities: either `CallHelper` plays the role of an activity, then the let the framework instantiate it or it doesn't (which seems to be the case here) then it should not inherit from `Activity`.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer? I didn't understand. It will be very good if you can tell me the solution.

Comment: Thanks. Finally it working all correctly now. CallHelper no more extend from Activity.